# Why is this two-inductor circuit first order?

Tags: circuit-analysis, math, circuit-theory

I have the following circuit with two inductors. Apparently this is a first order circuit (judging from my solutions for \$ i_1, i_2\$; and circuit simulations) but it's not intuitively clear to me why.

[image: pic]

Unfortunately the circuit parameters/initial conditions are a bit vague. I'm not given the exact form of \$I_0\$ (I assume it's most likely a step at t = 0 of height \$I_0\$). I'm given that \$ i_1(t=0)=I_0/2 \$. \$ i_2(t=0) \$ is not given.

My instinct is that since these inductors can't be combined in series or in parallel it should be a second order circuit. I see that there's a current source in parallel with each of the branches, but since the current isn't necessarily split the same way between each branch it seems that the branches will be coupled [(that is, I don't believe it's the same thing that's happening in this similar question).](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492287/first-order-circuit-that-looks-like-a-second-order-circuit)

Some initial analysis:

$$
I_0 = i_1 + i_2 \\
\frac{dI_0}{dt} = \frac{di_1}{dt} + \frac{di_2}{dt}
$$

Assuming that \$I_0\$ is constant in time after t = 0,

$$
\frac{di_1}{dt} = - \frac{di_2}{dt}
$$

And,

$$
-V_R-V_1+V_2=0 \\
\frac{di_2}{dt} = \frac{di_1}{dt}+ \frac{R}{L}i_1 \\
\frac{di_1}{dt} = -\frac{R}{2L}i_1 \\ 
i_1(t) = c_1 e^{-t \frac{R}{2L}}
$$

I can do the same thing (making use of \$ i_1 = I_0-i_2 \$) and solve for \$i_2\$:

$$
i_2(t) = c_2 e^{-t \frac{R}{2L}}+\frac{R}{2L} I_0
$$

I haven't solved for the coefficients but I think that's not important since the initial conditions shouldn't affect the order of the system, as far as I'm aware.

I think the biggest assumption I made here was that \$I_0\$ is constant in time, resulting in \$\frac{di_1}{dt} = - \frac{di_2}{dt}\$. The other thing is that since \$I_0 = i_1 + i_2\$, maybe this makes the branches "linearly dependent" (if that's the terminology here)?

I had thought that inductors/capacitors not being series/parallel reducible is the condition for them forming a higher-order system, but is that actually just a sufficient and not necessary condition?

Edit: It's occurred to me that if the source were set to 0 then the inductors would be in series. Not sure if setting inputs to 0 is how you're supposed to determine that stuff or if it's irrelevant/coincidental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why is this two-inductor circuit first order?*

Can you follow this argument: -

[image]

And clearly, this is a single order circuit.

> *since these inductors can't be combined in series or in parallel*

Oh yes they can (he said in a fake pantomime voice).

---

<sub>Given also that a current source can be regarded as having infinite impedance, the current source can be removed leaving two inductors in series with a resistor.</sub>

Comment: I agree the second circuit is definitely first order, but what justifies putting L2 in a series configuration when you change the current source to a voltage source?

Comment: [Thevenin and Norton equivalence](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/thevenin-norton-equivalencies/).

Comment: … he wrote, in a nearly fatherly voice, knowing that this is really something that knzy should be aware of, if they're dealing with electrical networks being used as filters.

Comment: V=sLIo it's not a constant. Maybe some math is still needed to be plausible.

Comment: @user287001 you only need the math to find Vo BUT that is not the point because, it doesn't matter if Vo is moving about like a juggler's eyeballs, it's still a first order circuit.

Comment: @user287001 I just went to my bookshelf and got out the "linear networks" scriptum from my first semester. It's the second or third lecture, so literally "second week of doing electrical engineering". I'm sure you can find that math yourself!

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  No problem, I know that the denominator states the order in this case. I wrote about the plausibility for someone who still struggles with things like this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm aware of it. I didn't recognize this was an application of it. Bit condescending.

Comment: @knzy didn't mean to be condescending, sorry, but I can see how it come across like that. I aimed for a humorous way of pointing out that it's probably pretty eye-opening to revisit basics – I forget stuff all the time.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "oh yes you did" etc...

Comment: @Andyaka I actually had some renewed confusion - I realized I've never done Thevenin analysis on cap/inductor circuits in the time domain, only frequency domain. I can see that in the time domain, you can't get a resistive relationship at the terminals with caps/inductors (for open circuit voltage or short circuit current). Since frequency domain analysis (I think) assumes steady state (sigma = 0) it's not obvious to me that the Thevenin/Norton relationships would hold for transient time domain analysis. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andyaka (part 2, sorry, comments are short) On the other hand, if initial conditions are 0 then caps/inductors are still linear, so that seems to support time domain thevenin equivalence, but the typical "find Zeq and then open circuit voltage/short circuit current" approach still seems to be broken.

Comment: @knzy as I said in comments earlier (to user287001) "it doesn't matter if Vo is moving about like a juggler's eyeballs" (or at 0 volts), if you can do the T/N transposition and put the inductors in series then the order of the circuit becomes clearer and simpler. Of course, if you don't define \$I_0\$ I can't help but, if it were assumed to be DC then the voltage source would be zero volts with an initial condition in the inductor of \$I_0\$. If \$I_0\$ is a ramping current then the voltage source would be a fixed voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you know of any sources that discuss this? I can't find anything in my books that talk about these time domain T/N analyses. I think I see what you're saying but I'm still a bit unsure so I'd be interested in looking at other references for time domain T/N with caps/inductors, instead of only sinusoidal steady state. In any case, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @knzy sorry I don’t know of sources off hand. If you find one, please link it in a comment for future reference.

Comment: I'm back from the future to add some info. First, to the main question from the post, in order for a system to be an nth order system there need to be n independent initial conditions. Because here there's a current source and \$ I_0 = i_1 + i_2\$, you can't independently specify the initial currents in the inductors, so the system must be first order. Second, re: time domain Thevenin, I came across this aside in a series of lectures by Prof Ali Hajimiri, where he explains finding a time domain Thevenin/Norton equivalent using the Heaviside operator: https://youtu.be/j9cAC__bY6o?t=413